# Dynamic addition of control in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, layout, controls

I have 2 panels. In 1 panel, I am adding a textbox dynamically. The panel that contains the textbox is increasing but this is conflicting with panel 2. How can I make a design that run-time design will not affect any controls? My first panel is on top when I am increasing textbox. This is increasing, but my 2nd panel is not coming down so both are conflicting. Any ideas about how to design this?

Thanks.

Comment: You should accept some answers for previous questions, people will be more likely to help you.

Comment: i think it will be easier of you actually show some code here

Comment: How to accept answer belongs to correct.Should i write Acceptation comment ?

Comment: click the check mark next to the correct anwser

Comment: I have 2 panels both are initializing at run time.I have taken one textbox in first panel after clikcing on button next textbox this is ceating new textbox but my 2 panel which is just below the 1st panel is overlapped.What i should improve in my design.

Comment: What GUI framework? WinForms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that it won't get any bigger than a fix height, you can set the height of your panel on every add operation as:

```
Panel.Height = Unit.Point(30 + Convert.ToInt32((Unit)Panel.Height));
```

and so on..
You can also set your second panels height the same way but scroll is a better idea if there is no limit in adding.

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace your 2 panels with 1 SplitContainer.
2. Set panel2.Autosize = false
3. Use the Anchors or the Dock property on the EditBox